# How to find Hierarchical order in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, loops

Assume an organization assigning employees to do annual reviews to others employees. Each ReviewID (who is an employee) can get reviewed by multiple employeeIDs. An employee can start/do the review only if the particular reviewID completed all his reviewIDs or has no pending reviewIDs.
Sample Data code:

```
    CREATE TABLE FindOrder
    (
    EmployeeID int
    ,ReviewID int
    )
     insert findorder
    values (1,3), (1,10), (1,12), (2,3), (2,5), (2,7), (3,0), (4,6), (5, 3), (6,0),      (7,0), (10,0), (12,5)
```

EmployeeIDs that have nothing to review (ReviewID=0) should be my first set of list (3, 6, 7, 10). EmployeedIDs who can start their review now are 4,5 ( should be my second set) as they need to review 6, 3 who dont have pending ReviewIDs. Here not employeeIDs 1 or 2 because 1 has reviewID 12 who did not complete all his reviews. so on...
Please let me know if I am still not clear.
I want to find the order levels such that level 0 is (6,10,7,3), level 1 is (5, 4), level 2 is (2, 12), level 3 is (1).

I tried this cte to find order:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT EmployeeID, ReviewID, 0 AS [Level] FROM FindOrder WHERE NETOUT = '0'
UNION  ALL
SELECT NN.EmployeeID, NN.ReviewID, [Level]+1  FROM FindOrder nn
JOIN CTE ON NN.ReviewID=CTE.EmployeeID
)
SELECT *  FROM CTE
```

But I get Employeeid 1 in level 1 and level 3. EmployeeID 1 should not come in level 1 as all ppl Employee 1 has to review did not complete their reviews ie., Employee 1 should come as Employee 12 did not complete his review. 
In general, new subset of data in recursive query above should have filtered EmployeeID 1 and 2.
Little tricky to explain but I hope I am clear now :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your level should actually be the longest path of reviews needed for a given employee.  For example, employee one has the following paths...

```
1->3
1->10
1->12->5->3
```

The level for this employee is the longest path, and if I'm understanding your question, the only one you care about.  Try this...

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT EmployeeID, ReviewID, 0 AS [Level] FROM FindOrder WHERE ReviewId = '0'
UNION  ALL
SELECT NN.EmployeeID, NN.ReviewID, [Level]+1  FROM FindOrder nn
JOIN CTE ON NN.ReviewID=CTE.EmployeeID
)
SELECT EmployeeId, MAX(Level) AS Level FROM CTE 
GROUP BY EmployeeID
ORDER BY MAX(Level)
```